# Develop Android app for Microsoft exchange OWA

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an application for my company which will allow logging into our Microsoft Exchange server and access mails.
I need some pointers on how to authenticate with the exchange server and download mails. I have a decent knowledge of Android. It would be really great if somebody could show me the right direction.

Comment: The first thing you want to do is see how much is available "for free".  This could well impact your design.  For example, you might wish to use ActiveSynch (instead of low-level SMTP send/POP3 or IMAP receive):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164816/android-tutorial-ref-to-access-contacts-email-and-contacts-using-exchange-a

Comment: check this answer. It may b helpful [jweb services for android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18957286/1421435

Answer (score 3):

I would start by finding a Java library which supports one of the protocols that Exchange supports, e.g. ActiveSync or IMAP.

For starters, look into the JavaMail library:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html

There's also a commercial ActiveSync library that you may be able to use:
http://www.independentsoft.de

Finally, you may be able to use Microsoft's Exchange Web Services API:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi